# How to edit the html (php?) of a wordpress page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

This is a hard question to phrase because I know that html is generated by the PHP files inside the themes.

I'm trying to add a line break and can do so going into classic mode while editing a page but this line break gets removed after time? So now I'm trying to go to the source and add it there (also any changes I want to make in the future).

Is this possible in `WordPress` or simply a feature we don't have? Please let me know if I'm wasting my time trying to do this.

Here is the php of my `page.php` file.

```
<?php
/*
* Content Page
*
* @package adios
* @since 1.0
*/
get_template_part('templates/global/page-before-content');
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

the_content();

wp_link_pages( array(
'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'adios' ),
'after'  => '</div>',
) );

// If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
if ((comments_open() || get_comments_number()) ) :
comments_template();
endif;
endwhile;
get_template_part('templates/global/page-after-content');
```

I don't know php only html and css so this is confusing to me, I'ved tried going to page-before-content and after-content but those don't seem to be useful. Also, yes I'm using a ftp server.

Here's the php from `page-before-content.php`

```
$layout = adios_get_opt('main-layout');
if ($layout == 'left_sidebar'): ?>
<div class="row">
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php elseif ($layout == 'right_sidebar'): ?>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

and `page-after-content.php`

```
$layout = adios_get_opt('main-layout');
if ($layout == 'left_sidebar'): ?>
</div>
</div><!-- .row -->
<?php elseif ($layout == 'right_sidebar'): ?>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- .row -->
<?php else: ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: can you please send the link or image.

Comment: What kind of "line break"? New line? Like with enter down one line? Where exactly do you want this "line break"? What is it supposed to do? Can't you just adjust CSS to make a larger divide between elements? Or are you asking to actually break a line of text somewhere using a `<br>`-tag or similar?

Comment: @Max Power can you please provide url if its live otherwise send screen where is problem you have?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I'm wanting to add a <br> tag but as I mentioned I can add it in classic mode while editing my page and it works but only for an hour or so then it's gone.

Comment: @VasimVanzara Sorry the site isn't live but I'll add the php from page-before-content and after-content and show you what that says.

Comment: @MaxPower Please check my answer

Comment: @MaxPower can you please provide a theme name you are using now.

Comment: @VasimVanzara Yes I see your answer, thankyou. I've checked these files but don't understand what they're doing enough to edit them to do what I want.

Comment: Where, exactly, do you want to create the line-break? And for what purpose? What is it you're trying to achive by adding a `<br>`-tag? Is it in the middle of a post? Or before/after the post? If it's the latter, I'm fairly certain this can be fixed purely in CSS. If it is inside the post, you'll probably not be able to do it in the template-files, as they mostly just handle fetching the post and displaying it, and rarely allow you to modify what is being fetched.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie It's one of the main headings. I think I just solved it by setting a max-width to its container. I would have preferred a line break but this may have to do. Frustrating we can't edit the html directly. Thanks for the help anyhow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install [TinyMCE Advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/). It has a option to keep the `<p>` and `<br>` tag.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the best solution, for my case at least. Cheers Cheng.

Comment: @MaxPower this plugin effect in whole page please read instruction before use.

Answer (score 1):

I have edited my answer this include number several ways,There is number of issue with tinymce plugin.Sometime its cause issue with some theme.I hope this following things are more helpful.

**There are a couple of different ways.**

- One is to use a slightly different editor:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

- The other way is to **disable the function that performs the removal**.  This is as simple as adding the following to your functions.php file:

`remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'); 
 remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop');`

- Yet another way is to use this plugin to enable/disable the **filters on a per post/page basis**:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpautop-control/

Comment: I'm not sure why it was put down. I'm yet to put it to theory but I'll bring it up, seems like a logical idea.